# Custom drop-down as an item in a kendo tree

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-dropdown, kendo-combobox, kendo-contextmenu

I am trying to create an item that is a button "show more" and when you press on it you can show a kind of context menu / drop down that all of the items in that drop down are with checkboxes and there is a search component in it too, so you can search some items in the dropdown by their name. For example: (instead of "c++,c#,Object c" it's should show "show more", i.e. static text)

[image]

I tried to use kendoContextMenu.  But I don't know if it's could work because the problem with context menu is that when I will click on a checkbox the menu will close. Please advise me of a way to do that or if you have an example of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The MultiSelect component might be a good starting point

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect.

My understanding is that MultiSelect does not have a "select more than one at a time in dropdown" feature.

You might consider using a pop up window and within that implement your own custom ui that features everything you want

- search term box
- scrolling list of selected and selectable items
- accept or cancel changes in selection

Regarding your dojo that extends drop down list, I can't code the extension for you.  However, changing the dataSource assignment to a setDataSource call will populate the extension component according to the template.

```
// kendo.ui.DropDownList.fn.dataSource = options.testItemSource;
   me.setDataSource(options.testItemSource);
```

Comment: OK, Thanks. I tried to extend the kendoDropDownList and combine it with multi select. https://dojo.telerik.com/ecObOMAR this is what I did... but the drop down is empty although I though I initialize it with dataSources... do you have an idea?

Comment: Also, the dropdownlist isn't so good for me, because I want that this popup will open when I click on a specific node in the kendo treeView object on the right position. So I need to extend popup ? or what else...?

Comment: The treeview *should* have some action indicator within the nodes render, for popup action this is typically the ellipsis.  I have used web-font icon .k-i-more-horizontal (Unicode: e032) with a guiding tooltip in past work. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/icons-web.  Ig you go the popup route and have more questions please make a new question and dojo.  For popup you I would just use regular components to implement the popup and only make an extension if I needed the composite ui 'experience' in three or more other places in the application.